# Can't get text link to vertically center next to a set of image links

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically center the elements in the black rectangle. So far, I have the icons vertically centered, but for some reason, the text link to the right of it is slightly off-centered. I tried adding padding to the top and bottom but it still stays off-centered. I've also tried adding a `vertical-align`, but that didn't work either.

[image]

I made a fiddle to make it easier: http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lxfw6q/1/

HTML

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul id="social-links">
    <li class="behance"><a href="/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/KTsyaQR.png" alt="Behance"></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cleZOWn.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
    <li class="instagram"><a href="/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/USZmKla.png" alt="Instagram"></a></li>
  </ul>

  <a class="contact" href="/contact">Get in touch</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#site-navigation {
background: #000;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#site-navigation #social-links {
border-right: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
display: inline-block;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0 30px 0 0;
padding: 25px 0;
padding-right: 30px
}

#site-navigation #social-links li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
}

#site-navigation #social-links img {
height: 26px;
}

#site-navigation .contact {
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

How would I get the text link (i.e. "Get in touch") to vertically center?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/z0Lxfw6q/3/

Comment: @abhitalks How does that work? I already had `display:inline-block` set to `.contact` and when I tried adding `vertical-align:middle` to `.contact`, it didn't work. Why does it work when you target `nav > a`? Isn't that the same as `.contact`?

Comment: No it is because of `vertical-align: middle` on `#social-links`. The last part is for other elements if you add up later on. Everything inside your `nav` (i.e. `ul` and `a`) if are `inline-block`, then you need `vertical-align` on each of those. Otherwise, you can always leave `vertical-align` and set them as `float: left` with `display: block`.

Comment: you need to set your line height the same as the box height

Comment: @J82: As I said, you have two elements inside your `nav`: `ul` and `a`. Both are `inline-block`, so need `vertical-align`. If you choose not to have them as `inline-block` then you need to `float` them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add     `vertical-align: middle` to `#site-navigation #social-links`.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lxfw6q/4/)

As pointed out by @4dgaurav, `inline-block` elements are always `vertical-align: bottom` by default. So you need to change that.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? The `a` element is not contained within `#social-links` so how does adding `vertical-align:middle` to `#social-links` have any effect on the `a` element?

Answer (score 1):

`inline-block` elements are `vertical-align: bottom` by default.

so just add `vertical-align: middle` to get it in middle where ever you want `inline-block` element vertically middle.

Comment: I tried adding `vertical-align: middle` to `.contact` but it stays the same: http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lxfw6q/2/